# URL Re-writing add new place button not going to desired page

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I am writing a URL redirect for my application, following is the code I have added in global.asax

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext incoming = HttpContext.Current;
        string oldpath = incoming.Request.Path.ToLower();
        //string placename = string.Empty;

        // Regular expressions to grab the productid and productname from the page.aspx
        //Here I am using regular expression to match tghe pattern.

        Regex regex = new Regex(@"displayplace/(\d+)/(.+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(oldpath);

        if (matches.Count > 0)
        {
            var referenceID = matches[0].Groups[1].ToString();
            var name = matches[0].Groups[2].ToString();
            incoming.RewritePath(string.Format("~/Layouts/Places/View.aspx?{0}={1}&{2}={3}", Source.Constants.Place.REFERENCE_ID, referenceID, Source.Constants.Place.NAME, name));
        }
    }
```

here is how my pages are stored in a folder

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I have an "Add new Place" button defined on my master page so that link is visible on all pages.
here is the markup for add new button link

```
<a runat="server" href="~/layouts/places/create">Add new Place</a>
```

If I type in browser places.local and click add new button, it goes to places.local/layouts/places/create (Work OK)

If I type (places.local/layouts/places/view?referenceID=32&name=test place change) it goes to (places.local/displayplace/32/test place change) which is OK

but

If I click on new button **from view page** it does not go anywhere but refreshes the page with this URL
(places.local/displayplace/32/create) **WRONG** and it should go to places.local/layouts/places/create

**Update**

worked for me, I used approach described here
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)

Comment: This code is going to run for every request to your site. It needs to be fast. Your usage of regex is incorrect, you don't want to run that regex compilation on every single request. Just do it once upfront.

Comment: yes that is correct, I need that regex compile only for view places, where should I move my code and what changes I should do?